# MVC3 - Unity/Unit of Work Pattern and Webservice implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, dependency-injection, unity-container, unit-of-work

I am a newbie to with unity and unit of work pattern and I am trying to write a code, which connects to my webservice and does all the work.
Everything goes well until I use the Database but I get lost when I try to use the webservice.

I have wasted my 2 precious days, searching every single possible article related to it and applying it to my code, but no luck till date.

I know, by writing connection string to web.config and calling it in dbcontext class controller will connect to the required database, but I am not connecting to any database, so what changes I need to do in web/app.config. Also, even if I write my connection logic in dbcontext constructor, it still searches and fills the dbcontext with sql server details. I presume thats happening because I am using DBSet.

Guys, you are requested to have a look at my code, I have done and show me some hope that I can do it. Let me know, if you want any other info related to the code that you want to see.

thanks

```
 DBCONTEXT

 public class CVSContext :  DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<CVSViewModel> CVS { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public CVSContext()
    {
        //CRM Start
            var clientCredentials = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials();
            clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
            clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";
            var serviceProxy = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri("http://Organization.svc"), null, clientCredentials, null);
            serviceProxy.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ServiceProxy", serviceProxy);
          //CRM End
    }
 }
```

GENERIC REPOSITORY

```
   public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
   {
    internal CVSContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(CVSContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
   }
```

UNIT OF WORK

```
   public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();
}

public interface IDALContext : IUnitOfWork
{
    ICVSRepository CVS { get; set; }

    IContactRepository Contacts { get; set; }

    //IAccountRepository Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class DALContext : IDALContext
{
    private CVSContext dbContext;
    private ICVSRepository cvs;
    private IContactRepository contacts;
   // private IAccountRepository accounts;

    public DALContext()
    {
        dbContext = new CVSContext();
    }

    public ICVSRepository CVS
    {
        get
        {
            if (cvs == null)
                cvs = new CVSRepository(dbContext);
            return cvs;
        }

        set
        {
            if (cvs == value)
                cvs = value;
        }
    }

    public IContactRepository Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (contacts == null)
                contacts = new ContactRepository(dbContext);
            return contacts;
        }

        set
        {
            if (contacts == value)
                contacts = value;
        }
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(contacts != null)
            contacts.Dispose();
        //if(accounts != null)
        //    accounts.Dispose();
        if(dbContext != null)
            dbContext.Dispose();

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
  }
```

SERVICE

```
 public interface ICVSService
{
    Contact CreateContact(Guid contactName, string productName, int price);

    List<CVSViewModel> GetCVS();
    List<Contact> GetContacts();
    List<Account> GetAccounts();
}

public class CVSService : ICVSService, IDisposable
{
    private IDALContext context;

    public CVSService(IDALContext dal)
    {
        context = dal;
    }

    public List<CVSViewModel> GetCVS()
    {
        return context.CVS.All().ToList();
    }

    public List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        return context.Contacts.All().ToList();
    }

    public List<Account> GetAccounts()
    {
        return context.Accounts.All().ToList();
    }

    public Contact CreateContact(Guid contactName, string accountName, int price)
    {
        var contact = new Contact() { ContactId = contactName };

        var account = new Account() { ContactName = accountName,  Rent  = price, Contact = contact };

        //context.Contacts.Create(contact);
        context.SaveChanges();

        return contact;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (context != null)
            context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {         
        ViewData.Model = service.GetContacts();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Sooo.... what is it exactly you want to know?

Comment: @Steven: what i want to know that, how can i consume the webservice, because if i use dbset or dbcontext, i dont get any reference to the webservice, although i specify it in the dbcontext constructor. may be i dont know, how to code it. please help me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your question. A DbContext is an abstraction over databases, not over web services. If you're goal is use the DbContext to communicate with a web service, you will fail. This is not possible.

Comment: @Steven: let me put this in another words. I want to call the webservice, how would I do it or what approach I need to follow, and if you say dbcontext is abstraction over db and ws, then what changes I would make to replace the existing dbcontext with something related to webservice. Let me know, if that makes you clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's all about proper abstractions. The common abstraction that is used between some data source (could be a db or ws) is the Repository pattern, or at a higher level the Unit of Work pattern. In fact Entity Framework `DbContext` is an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern, but it is tailored for databases. You can't use to communicate with a web service.

In that case you will have to write your own `IRepository<T>` abstraction and have a database specific implementation that uses a `DbContext` under the covers and a web service specific implementation that wraps a web service client proxy under the covers.

However, when your application gets more complex, you often find yourself wanting to have some sort of transaction like behavior. This is what the Unit of Work pattern if for: it presents a business transaction. Using the unit of work pattern to wrap multiple WS calls however, will get painful very soon. It's a lot of work to get right and in that case you will be much better of using a message based architecture.

With a message based architecture you define a single atomic operation (a business transaction or use case) as a specific message, for instance:

```
public class MoveCustomerCommand
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Address NewAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is just an object (DTO) with a set of properties, but without behavior. Nice about this is that you can pass these kinds of objects over the wire using WCF or any other technology or process them locally without the need for the consumer to know.

Take a look at [this article that describes it in detail](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). [This article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) builds on top of that model and describes how you can write highly maintainable WCF services using this model.